# Cannot POST with ExpressJS and CSRF

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, csrf

I'm newbie with node.js and express and I'm trying to protect some url's with a token. I generate the token correctly but when I post a form with this token I've got an error in my browser with this text "Cannot POST /process" where /process is the url where I send the data from my form. In my console I haven't any error. So, I don't know what is happend or what am I doing wrong :(

The code is divided in three files, main file called (index.js) where I require the second file (routes-api.js) and the html file with the form.

**index.js**

```
//Creación de un servidor con express
const express = require("express");
const app = express();  //Inicializamos express

//Accedemos a otros módulos
const morgan = require("morgan");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

//Accedemos a propiedades de configuración
const config = require("./config");

//Rutas
const routes = require("./routes");
const routesAPI = require("./routes-api");

//Settings
app.set("app-name", config.server);
app.set("port", config.port);
app.set("super-secret", config.secret);

//Middlewares
// use body parser so we can get info from POST and/or URL parameters
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan("dev")); //Log request to the console
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log("Pasamos por la segunda función!!!");
    next();
});

//Routing
app.use("/api", routesAPI);
app.use(routes);

//Server
app.listen(app.get("port"), () => {
    console.log("Servidor " +  app.get("app-name") + " escuchando!!!");
});   //Creamos el servidor con express
```

**route-api.js**

```
const csrf = require('csurf');
const path = require("path");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

// setup route middlewares
var csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true });
var parseForm = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

router.get("/", csrfProtection, (req, res) => {
    console.log("crsf: " + req.csrfToken());
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/send.html'), { csrfToken: req.csrfToken() });    
});

router.post('/process', parseForm, csrfProtection, function(req, res) {
    console.log("csrf: " + req.body._csrf + " color: " + req.body.favoriteColor);
    res.send('data is being processed');
});

module.exports = router;
```

**send.html**

```
<form action="/process" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="_csrf" value="{{csrfToken}}">

    Favorite color: <input type="text" name="favoriteColor">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

What am I doing wrong to get the error "Cannot POST /process" when I send the form to the server?

Comment: I am not an express user but shouldnt the URL be /api/process? in the form action?

Comment: OMG!!! What a mistake!!! Thank you so much @akaphenom!!!